# Create third column from 2 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I show a column where the values from the first column completes the missing values of the second column?

I want this result (red marked column):

[image: select example]

Comment: It is better to provide examples on text not as image also image is not loading

Comment: Just use Stack Overflow's native image handling rather than rolling your own.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/B3PFz

Comment: @AdrianSandoval Use `CASE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use case as below:

```
Select *, ThirdColumn = Case when SecondColumn is null then FirstColumn else SecondColumn End
   FourthColumn = Row_Number() over(partition by coalesce(SecondColumn,FirstColumn) order by Id)
   from yourtable
```

or with coalesce

```
Select *, ThirdColumn = coalesce(SecondColumn,FirstColumn)
   FourthColumn = Row_Number() over(partition by coalesce(SecondColumn,FirstColumn) order by Id)
   from yourtable
```

Comment: I want to create a fourth column with this:  
                                                                                                           
`select * from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, Coalesce(column1, column2) as column3, row_number() over(partition by column0 order by [column3]) as column4 from myTable) ti`
                                                                                                                     i want this result: (red marked column)                          
              [example](http://imgur.com/a/Vq5qf)

Comment: Updated results for 4th column

Comment: Thanks but this query not works because the ThirdColumn (coalesce or Case), has the values of the firstColumn, if i invert the coalesce the ThirdColumn contains the values of SecondColumn

[link](http://imgur.com/a/WJCQI)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Column1, Column2, Coalesce(column2, Column1)
```

That's assuming ALL you care about is column2 UNLESS there's a value in column1, at which point you want column1.

Your question's not overtly clear.

Comment: I want to create a fourth column with this:

`select * from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, Coalesce(column1, column2) as column3, row_number() over(partition by column0 order by [column3]) as column4 from myTable) ti`

i want this result: (red marked column)

[link] (http://imgur.com/a/Vq5qf)

Comment: You should create a new question for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CASE`:

```
SELECT COL1 , COL2 , COL3 = CASE WHEN COL1 IS NOT NULL THEN COL1 ELSE COL2 END
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Using `coalesce` :

```
SELECT * ,coalesce(COL1,COL2) AS COL3
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Comment: Please don't steal my answer. You had a perfectly good one, don't just duplicate mine.

Comment: @RachelAmbler I don't think so , if you think that I steal your work , flag mine.

Comment: How is your answer on coalesce ANY different from mine? Your original answer was fine. You then added coalesce minutes after my version

Comment: I don't see even your answer , as I say you can flag it if you think so.

Comment: You tried refreshing the page? And no I'm not flagging it - the first part of your answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: How did you not see it? You should always check what the other answers say. As it stands this is just a composite of two answers that were posted before yours.

Comment: @MartinSmith You think so? see my comment first in the question, I was writing my answer.

Comment: Yes. Order the answers by oldest. There is a `COALESCE` answer and a `CASE` answer above yours. And when your answer was first posted it just mentioned `CASE` with `COALESCE` being edited in during the grace period.

Comment: Your answer is wrong anyway. According to the OP the second column should be given UNLESS there's a value in only the first, at which point the first column should be returned. Your answers assume Col1 is always primary UNLESS there's a value in only in col2.

Comment: I want to create a fourth column with this:  
                                                                                                           
`select * from (select ID, column0, column1, column2, Coalesce(column1, column2) as column3, row_number() over(partition by column0 order by [column3]) as column4 from myTable) ti`
                                                                                                                     i want this result: (red marked column)                          
              [link](http://imgur.com/a/Vq5qf)

Comment: @AdrianSandoval You can update your question , or ask another one.